# What SOQL query would return the columns that count towards object Custom Fields limit

Tags: salesforce, soql

There are object limits for each object you have in salesforce. I am wondering what Salesforce API would give you all the fields that are going towards each limit. How would I do this?

I have tried using the tooling API but it's not working... maybe I don't know where to look

```
SELECT
BUSINESSOWNERID
,BUSINESSSTATUS
,DATATYPE
,DESCRIPTION
,DEVELOPERNAME
,ID
,ISCALCULATED
,ISCOMPOUND
,ISFIELDHISTORYTRACKED
,LABEL
,LASTMODIFIEDBYID
,LASTMODIFIEDDATE
,MasterLabel
,QUALIFIEDAPINAME
,NAMESPACEPREFIX
,VALUETYPEID
,ENTITYDEFINITIONID
FROM FIELDDEFINITION
WHERE ENTITYDEFINITIONID ='Account'
```

But this doesn't return a filterable result where I can align the data to the limit numbers. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

We need to check the Use tooling API in query Editor Tab from Developer console or

You can use salesforce workbench to see the results in list
[image]